# NSString issues

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have an NSString that gets assigned a string value.  How do I take this `NSString` and insert `@"-thumbnail"` between the file's name and its extension?

In other words, how do I go from:

```
NSString *fileName = @"myFile.png";
```

to:

```
NSString *thumbnailName = [NSString someMagicFunction...]
NSLog(@"%@", thumbnailName);  // Should Output "myFile-thumbnail.png"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The NSString additions for path components can come in handy, specifically: [pathExtension](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/pathExtension) and [stringByDeletingPathExtension](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByDeletingPathExtension)

***Edit:*** see also: [stringByAppendingPathExtension:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingPathExtension:) (as pointed out by [Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong))

```
NSString * ext = [fileName pathExtension];
NSString * baseName = [fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString * thumbBase = [baseName stringByAppendingString:@"-thumbnail"];
NSString * thumbnailName = [thumbBase stringByAppendingPathExtension:ext];
```

If you really want that `magicFunction` to exist, you can add a category method to NSString like so:

```
@interface NSString (MoreMagic)
- (NSString *)stringByAddingFileSuffix:(NSString *)suffix;
@end

@implementation NSString (MoreMagic)
- (NSString *)stringByAddingFileSuffix:(NSString *)suffix
{
    NSString * extension = [self pathExtension];
    NSString * baseName = [self stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSString * thumbBase = [baseName stringByAppendingString:suffix];
    return [thumbBase stringByAppendingPathExtension:extension];
}
@end
```

To be used as follows:

```
NSString * thumbnailName = [fileName stringByAddingFileSuffix:@"-thumbnail"];
```

Comment: +1 while good, you may also want to check out `-stringByAppendingPathExtension:`

Comment: @Dave DeLong: I elected not to use it for the sake of brevity, but you are right. I will edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain of your filenames, you could also simply do:

```
[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@"-thumbnail."]
```

But the path handling stuff is cleaner (doesn't care how many "." you have in the name) and good to know about for trickier cases.

Answer (score 0):

We've got an opensource category for just that: [-[NSString ks_stringWithPathSuffix:]](https://github.com/karelia/KSFileUtilities/blob/master/KSPathUtilities.m)