# cocoa-touch How to insert strings into specific length position in string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
NSString * myText = @"This is my really long text view";
NSUInterger textLenght = [myText length]; //NSLog 32
```

How can I insert any text at the chosen length position. at length 10, for example?

I tried this but it does not work!

```
NSRange textRange = [myText rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:10];
[myText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:textRange withString:@"NEW"];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551214/nsstring-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign it:

```
myText=[myText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:textRange withString:@"NEW"];
```

A NSString is immutable, you can't change it's characters,that's why stringByReplacingCharactersInRange doesn't rearrange the characters, but returns another string built from scratch.

Take into consideration to use a [NSMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSMutableString * myText = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString: @"This is my really long text view"];
NSRange textRange = [myText rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:10];
[myText replaceCharactersInRange: textRange withString:@"NEW"];
```